# Oracle: Search an entire DB for a string: Error ORA-00911

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, ora-00911

I have created the PL/SQL stored procedure below to search an entire Oracle11g database for a string (srchstr) and return the table and column where that string was found to a table called VALUESEARCHRESULTS.

The procedure has ran successfully in Oracle XE via SQL Developer as a user. However, when try to run it as user SYS in Oracle11g for schema ABC, I receive the following error:

**ORA-00911: invalid character**
Cause: identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than letters and numbers. $#_ are also allowed after the first character. Identifiers enclosed by double quotes may contain any character other than a double quote. Alternative quotes (q"#...#") cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as delimiters. For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language Reference Manual.

Does anyone know why this may be?  Please see my code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABC.FIND_STRING(p_str IN VARCHAR2) authid current_user is
  l_query    clob;
  srchstr    varchar2(30) := '';
  r_cname    varchar2(30) := '';
  l_case     clob;
  l_runquery boolean;
  l_tname    varchar2(30);
  l_cname    varchar2(30);
begin
   dbms_application_info.set_client_info( '%' || upper(p_str) || '%' );

   for x in (select * from user_tables)
   loop
       l_query := 'select ''' || x.table_name || ''', $$
                     from ' || x.table_name || '
                    where rownum = 1 and ( 1=0 ';
       l_case := 'case ';
       l_runquery := FALSE;
       for y in ( select *
                    from user_tab_columns
                   where table_name = x.table_name
                     and (data_type in('CHAR', 'DATE', 'FLOAT', 'NCHAR', 'NUMBER', 'NVARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR2' )
                       or data_type like 'INTERVAL%' or data_type like 'TIMESTAMP%' )
                )
       loop
           l_runquery := TRUE;
           l_query := l_query || ' or upper(' || y.column_name ||
                      ') like userenv(''client_info'') ';
           l_case := l_case || ' when upper(' || y.column_name ||
                     ') like userenv(''client_info'') then ''' ||
                     y.column_name || '''';
       end loop;
       if ( l_runquery )
       then
           l_case := l_case || ' else NULL end';
           l_query := replace( l_query, '$$', l_case ) || ')';
           begin
              execute immediate l_query into l_tname, l_cname;
              r_cname := l_cname;
              dbms_application_info.read_client_info(srchstr);
              insert into ABC.ValueSearchResults (resulttable, resultcolumn, searchstring) values (x.table_name, r_cname, srchstr);
               dbms_output.put_line
               ( srchstr || ' found in ' || l_tname || '.' || l_cname );
           exception
               when no_data_found then
                   dbms_output.put_line
                   ( srchstr || ' has no hits in ' || x.table_name );
           end;
          end if;
        end loop;
       end;
```

**EDIT**: The stored procedure above compiles without error. The code below executes the stored procedure by passing values from a table into the stored procedure. The error shows when the code below is ran:

```
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (SELECT ControlValue FROM ABC.ControlValues) LOOP
       ABC.FIND_STRING(c.ControlValue);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: When you're dealing with dynamic SQL, it is incredibly helpful to log the SQL statement that you are executing particularly when you get an error.  If you can post the generated SQL statement that is failing, it's much easier to figure out where the bug is.  My wager is that you have some case-sensitive identifiers so you need to enclose your table and column names in the dynamic SQL statement in double quotes.  Separately, I can't imagine why you would want to let users search NUMBER or DATE or TIMESTAMP columns for a particular string-- that doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: Thank you Justin - I've updated my question to include the code that executes the stored procedure. I have included NUMBER, DATE, and TIMESTAMP given that I will be searching for numbers, dates, etc. in some cases. I will also try using the double quotes.

Comment: The code calling your stored procedure isn't that interesting.  It's the SQL statement that you build up an pass to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` that you need to log and post.  How are you going to search for a `DATE` using this function given that you are accepting a string as a parameter.  If you pass in a string "March 1 2013", your function would need to know the format of the string and call `to_char( date_column, 'Month DD YYYY"` before doing the comparison.  Unless you want the results to vary based on the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.

Comment: Lots of questions ... "... when try to run it as user SYS in Oracle11g for schema ABC ..." Do you mean that you are executing this procedure by connecting as user SYS and executing this? How are you running it for a particular schema if you do that? Seem like you'd need to accept a schema name and query ALL_TABLES not USER_TABLES, and also specify DROPPED = 'NO'. And why are you setting client_info with the string?

Comment: I am only searching for values that are guaranteed to be in the database. So for date, I will always have the correct date format. As for the statement that passes to the execute immediate, it is created in the beginning of the stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you for replying David. Yes, I am trying to run this as user SYS on a particular schema. Is that incorrect? A user was logged in as SYS when they created the schema. Yes, good point about all_tables and dropped. In regards to the client_info, I am modeling my code from Tom's at this link: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:37336026927381#42426083757635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a resolution for the issue I initially raised.

**Cause of error: Not specifying a schema; only grabbing user-specific tables.**

While the stored procedure would execute when deployed as user ABC, the error generated when running the stored procedure as a user other ABC. It appeared the same table name existed in multiple schemas. Thus, adding an OWNER variable specified the schema associated with the table name and eliminated the error.

Additionally, the procedure was originally searching for USER_TABLES. This limited the results to only the tables of the current schema. By replacing USER_TABLES with DBA_TABLES, the stored procedure's search spanned through all tables of the database.

See below for the corrected code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE FIND_STRING(
    p_str IN VARCHAR2) authid current_user
IS
  l_query CLOB;
  srchstr VARCHAR2(100) := '';
  r_cname VARCHAR2(100) := '';
  l_case CLOB;
  l_runquery BOOLEAN;
  l_tname    VARCHAR2(100);
  l_cname    VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  dbms_application_info.set_client_info( '%' || upper(p_str) || '%' );
  FOR x  IN
  (SELECT *
  FROM dba_tables
  WHERE table_name    <> 'CONTROLVALUES'
  AND table_name      <> 'VALUESEARCHRESULTS'
  AND tablespace_name <> 'SYSTEM'
  AND tablespace_name <> 'SYSAUX'
  AND tablespace_name <> 'TEMP'
  AND tablespace_name <> 'UNDOTBS1'
  )
  LOOP
    l_query    := 'select ''' || x.owner || '.' || x.table_name || ''', $$                         
from ' || x.owner || '.' || x.table_name || '                         
where rownum = 1 and ( 1=0 ';
    l_case     := 'case ';
    l_runquery := FALSE;
    FOR y  IN
    (SELECT *
    FROM dba_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = x.table_name
    AND owner        = x.owner
    AND (data_type  IN ( 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'FLOAT', 'NCHAR', 'NUMBER', 'NVARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR2' )
    OR data_type LIKE 'INTERVAL%'
    OR data_type LIKE 'TIMESTAMP%' )
    )
    LOOP
      l_runquery := TRUE;
      l_query    := l_query || ' or upper(' || y.column_name || ') like userenv    (''client_info'') ';
      l_case     := l_case || ' when upper(' || y.column_name || ') like userenv    (''client_info'') then ''' || y.column_name || '''';
    END LOOP;
    IF ( l_runquery ) THEN
      l_case  := l_case || ' else NULL end';
      l_query := REPLACE( l_query, '$$', l_case ) || ')';
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE immediate l_query INTO l_tname, l_cname;
        r_cname := l_cname;
        dbms_application_info.read_client_info(srchstr);
        INSERT
        INTO VALUESEARCHRESULTS
          (
            resulttable,
            resultcolumn,
            searchstring
          )
          VALUES
          (
            x.table_name,
            r_cname,
            srchstr
          );
        dbms_output.put_line ( srchstr || ' found in ' || l_tname || '.' || l_cname );
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line ( srchstr || ' has no hits in ' || x.owner || '.' || x.table_name );
      END;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```